# PySpark : How to use df.na.fill() to convert all null values including string and interger types to blank(\N)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pyspark is there any way to use df.na.fill() to convert all null values including string and interger types to blank(\N)

I tried `df.na.fill("\\N")`. But it converting only String values to blank(\N).

Help me to find out a way to solve this

Comment: In pyspark you cannot have a string value `"\\N"` in an integer column.

Comment: @ScootCork Okay. So is there anyway to make it blank. In hive text format file i can see null values are populated as \N. But when I write as parquet from spark it is coming as null. I want null values to be \N in parquet format as well

Comment: It depends on why you want this, you could cast the numeric columns to string first but don't know if that suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

One is null and the other is Unknown. They are two different datatypes. you can replace one at a time. If you successfully replace nulls in an integer dtype with `\\N` it will be turned into a string. Lets try

```
tup = [(1, "a"), (None, "null"), (2, "a"), (1, None), (2, "b"), (3, "b")]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tup, ["id", "category"])
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
```

Replace Nulls

```
from functools import reduce
df1 = reduce(lambda df, c: df.withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, 'null', '\\N')),df.columns, df).na.fill('\\N')
df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- category: string (nullable = false)
```